# Как реализовать отображение дробной части в DevExpress GridControl по умолчанию(WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

Как реализовать отображение дробной части в DevExpress GridControl по умолчанию(WPF). Имеется гридконтрол, там поля с числовыми значениями. Проблема в том, что необходимо оябзательно указыватть дробную часть, даже если оно нулевое. Например так 5.000

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть в сторону `123.456789.ToString("0.0000")`, может поможет Вам

Comment: Если у вас идет привязка, то задайте нужный `StringFormat` и все.

Comment: Даже и того проще, там есть свойство DisplayFormat, ему присваиваем значение =F.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как - то так

```
 <dxGrid:DateColumn FieldName="boubleValues" DisplayFormat="F"/>
```

Как раз 2 знака после запятой.